# NaN and Singular matrix error in Solution of Simultaneous Linear Equations

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, linear-algebra

I have implemented Gaussian elimination, back substitution, and solver functions to solve Simultaneous Linear Equations. Somehow I'm flowing through the code but I don't understand why I'm getting an error for the given function and it's as follows:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[4., -1., -1., -1.],
              [-1., 3., 0., -1.],
              [-1., 3., 0., -1.],
              [-1., -1., -1., 4.]])

v = np.array([5.,0.,5.,0.])

def gaussian_elimination(A, v):
    N = len(v) # A should be shaped (N,N), and v is a (N,) vector
    A_new = np.copy(A) # make copies, so our elimination doesn't effect original
    v_new = np.copy(v)

    for m in range(N):
        # divide by the diagonal element to normalize
        div = A_new[m, m]
        A_new[m,:] /= div
        v_new[m] /= div

        # now subtract from the lower rows
        for i in range(m+1, N):
            mult = A_new[i, m]
            A_new[i,:] -= mult * A_new[m,:]
            v_new[i] -= mult * v_new[m]

    return A_new,v_new


def backsubstitution(A, v):
    N = len(v) # A should be shaped (N,N), and v is (N,) vector
    x = np.empty(N, float) # holds results we will return

    for m in range(N-1, -1, -1):
        x[m] = v[m]
        for i in range(m+1, N):
            x[m] -= A[m, i] * x[i]
    return x

def linear_system_solve(A, v):
    A_upper, v_upper = gaussian_elimination(A, v)
    x = backsubstitution(A_upper, v_upper)
    return x

#system of equations using the gaussian elimination function
x = linear_system_solve(A, v)
print(A)
print(v)
print(x)

#the NumPy linear algebra library to solve the same system
x2 = np.linalg.solve(A, v)
print( x2 )
```

**For gaussian elimination I'm getting the following error:**

```
[[ 4. -1. -1. -1.]
 [-1.  3.  0. -1.]
 [-1.  3.  0. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1.  4.]]
[5. 0. 5. 0.]
[nan nan nan nan]
```

**For linear algebra library I'm getting the following error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-cc74f430c404> in <module>()
      1 # use the NumPy linear algebra library to solve the same system here
      2 
----> 3 x2 = np.linalg.solve(A, v)
      4 print( x2 )

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in solve(a, b)
    392     signature = 'DD->D' if isComplexType(t) else 'dd->d'
    393     extobj = get_linalg_error_extobj(_raise_linalgerror_singular)
--> 394     r = gufunc(a, b, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
    395 
    396     return wrap(r.astype(result_t, copy=False))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in 
_raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag)
     87 
     88 def _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag):
---> 89     raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
     90 
     91 def _raise_linalgerror_nonposdef(err, flag):

LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Can anyone please help me to understand the glitch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure you implemented requires the matrix to be of [full rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) and so does [`np.linalg.solve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html). Your matrix `A`, however, is not of full rank since rows `A[1]` and `A[2]` are not lineraly independent. Otherwise, your code works fine. See the following example with modified data.

```
# set A[2, 2] to 1
A = np.array([[ 4., -1., -1., -1.],
              [-1.,  3.,  0., -1.],
              [-1.,  3.,  1., -1.],
              [-1., -1., -1.,  4.]])

v = np.array([5., 0., 5., 0.])

np.allclose(np.linalg.solve(A, v), linear_system_solve(A, v))    # True
```

You can check the rank of a matrix using [`np.linalg.matrix_rank`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_rank.html).

Comment: Thanks, I understood the problem.@MaxPowers